# How to determine the span of two vectors: $(4,2)$ and $(1, 3)$

Tags: calculus, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

How to determine the span of two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$:

$(4,2)$ and $(1, 3)$

Do I subtract them? I don't how I'd solve this. Thanks in advance. In my question the vectors are like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
2
\end{bmatrix}

But that doesn't matter, right?

Would the vector equation $x_1v_1 + x_2v_2$ = b be consistent for any b in $\mathbb R^2$
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span is just the possible linear combinations of the two vectors...
$$Span\{(4,2),(1,3)\}=\{a(4,2)+b(1,3);a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Comment: so infinity pretty much?

Comment: @DoctorReality more like all of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: How @Stephen Goree said it will be all $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: thx, so that means the vector equation $x_1v_1 + x_2v_2$ = b be consistent for any b in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: You are asking if the solution of $x_1v_1+x_2v_2=b$ for any fixed $b$ is all $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: yes that is it sir

Comment: Try for $b=(0,0)$. What is the solution for that?

Comment: $x1 =0$ and$ x2 = 0$?

Comment: Yes... And that is not all $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: why would it not be all r^2. is 0,0 not in r^2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112696/discussion-between-pam1499-and-doctor-reality).

Answer (score 2):

The span of a set of vectors, is the set of every linear combination that you can "create" from those vectors.

So in your example $a(4,2)+b(1,3)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

So for example $(5,5)$ is in the span of your vectors, because $1\cdot (4,2)+1\cdot (1,3)=(5,5)$

Also $(3,-1)$ is in the span as $(4,2)-(1,3)=(3,-1)$.

In general every vector of the form $(4a+b,2a+3b)$ are in the span.

Comment: thx, so that means the vector equation $x_1v_1 + x_2v_2$ = b be consistent for any b in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @Doctor Reality What do you mean by vector equation? Are $x_1, x_2, v_1, v_2$ all supposed to be vectors? How do you multiply two vectors? What do you mean with "consistent for any $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I do not understand your question at the moment.

Comment: like v1 is a and v2 is b and x1 is any coefficient and x2 is any coefficient and b is any number

Comment: @DoctorReality Excuse me, I am still not getting what your exact question is here, but you are already discussing this question with PAM1499, so I think that should clarify it eventually. If not feel free to ask, or try to rephrase your question. :)

Comment: sorry man, it's just exactly what the question says

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  You can write the vectors vertically or horizontally, it really doesn't matter.

The span of any $n$ vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is by definition the set of all linear combinations of them, $\rm{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}=\{a_1v_1+\dots+a_nv_n|a_i\in\Bbb F\, \forall i\}$.

(This generalizes to infinite dimensions as well.)

(Also, if the vectors are linearly independent, you get a copy of $\Bbb F^n$.  So in this case you get the whole $\Bbb R^2$.)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said (or suggested), since (4,2) and (1,3) are **linearly independent**, their span equals all of $R^2.$

By linear independence, I mean that (for example) **there is no scalar** 
$k \in \mathbb{R} \;\ni \;(4,2) = k \times (1,3).$

The following analysis proves that any element (x,y) that is in $R^2$ is also 
in the span of (4,2) : (1,3).

Desired to find scalars $r,s$ such that 
$[E_1] \;r \times (4,2) \;+\; s \times (1,3) \;=\; (x,y).$

By $E_1,$ 
$[E_2] \;r(4) + s(1) = x$ and 
$[E_3] \;r(2) + s(3) = y$.

Multiplying $E_3$ by 2 and subtracting it from $E_2$ gives 
$s(-5) = (x - 2y)$. 
Similarly, multiplying $E_2$ by 3 and subtracting it from $E_3$ gives 
$r(-10) = y - 3x.$

By the above analysis, it has been demonstrated that for any $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R^2},$ 
there exist scalars $r = (-1/10)(y - 3x)$ and 
$s = (-1/5)(x - 2y)$ 
such that $E_1$ is satisfied.

Comment: thx homie appreciate the other perspectivez